# How to add global event listener for kendo modals and do something?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm new to kendojs 
What I'm trying to do:
I want to disable scrolling on html and body element when ever a modal is opened.
and enable scrolling when all modals are closed.

so how can i set a global listener to detect when a kendo modal is opened or closed?

I've tried:

```
kendo.ui.Dialog.bind("open", function(){
    console.log("dialog is opened");
})
```

i've also tried

```
$(document).data("kendoDailog").bind("open", function(){})
```

i've also tried

```
kendo.ui.Dialog.fn.open = function(){}

$(document).data(".k-widget.k-window.k-dialog").bind("open", function() {
    console.log("stan");
});

$(document).data("kendDialog").addEventListener("open", function(){
    console.log("Dialog Modal is opened");
});

kendo.ui.Dialog.fn.bind("open",function(e,s){
    console.log(e); console.log(s)
})

kendo.ui.Dialog.bind("open", function(){
    console.log("tester");
});
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yeah, I've tried:
kendo.ui.Dialog.bind("open", function(){console.log("dialog is opened");})

i've also tried $(document).data("kendoDailog").bind("open", function(){})

i've also tried kendo.ui.fn.open = function(){}

Comment: Most frameworks don't fire event when they open their modals. The DOM method for dispatching events is [Event​Target​.dispatch​Event()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). The jQuery method is [.trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution(but it requires more work):
on every main modal, add this in the options object:

```
open: function(e) {
  $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
},
close: function() {
  $("html, body").css("overflow", "visible");
}
```